# directory path as command line argument in bash

Tags: linux, bash, directory, command-line-arguments

The following bash script finds a `.txt` file from the given directory path, then changes one word (change mountain to sea) from the `.txt` file

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=`find /home/abc/Documents/2011.11.* -type f -name "abc.txt"`
sed -e 's/mountain/sea/g' $FILE
```

The output I am getting is ok in this case.
My problem is if I want to give the directory path as command line argument then it is not working. Suppose, I modify my bash script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=`find $1 -type f -name "abc.txt"`
sed -e 's/mountain/sea/g' $FILE
```

and invoke it like:

```
./test.sh /home/abc/Documents/2011.11.*
```

Error is:

```
./test.sh: line 2: /home/abc/Documents/2011.11.10/abc.txt: Permission denied
```

Can anybody suggest how to access directory path as command line argument?

Comment: `./test.sh *.txt` will make the shell expand that wildcard before test.sh gets invoked, so it'd be functionally identical to `./test.sh file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt etc...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line should be:

```
FILE=`find "$@" -type f -name "abc.txt"`
```

The wildcard will be expanded before calling the script, so you need to use `"$@"` to get all the directories that it expands to and pass these as the arguments to `find`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass `.*` to your script.

Have your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# some sanity checks here
path="$1"

find "$path".* -type f -name "abc.txt" -exec sed -i.bak 's/mountain/sea/g' '{}' \;
```

And run it like:

```
./test.sh "/home/abc/Documents/2011.11"
```

**PS:** See how sed can be invoked directly from find itself using `-exec` option.

Comment: The name of the directory isn't `2011.11`, it's `2011.11.10`. He needs the wildcard to make it find the directory with any suffix.